# Converting svg to png using canvas toDataURL doesn't work in Safari on Mac

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, svg, safari

I'm trying to convert svg xml with embedded images using HTML5 Canvas toDataURL method. Embedded image url do not convert, and that's somewhat explainable as a CORS security concern.

However, if I use a base64 embedded image, it works fine in IE, Chrome and Firefox. But it doesn't work at all in Safari on Mac.

See this JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w2c6zw8c/1/

```
var preview2 = document.getElementById("preview2");
preview2.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

This really should be a simple svg to png conversion and should work.

Any advice or ideas?

Comment: Seems to be a [known issue](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=129172)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although the last comment on that bug says that it seems to be resolved.

Comment: A very interesting thing is that if you open developers tools in Safari on a mac, and get the base64 image generated out of it, it actually is the correct and expected image. After reviewing the image in developer tools, it also starts showing correctly in the web page after that, but if you open it in another tab, the issue is still there.